# I have problem translating C code in fortran

Tags: c, fortran

```
for(i=1;i<=ntype;i++)
        for(cnt=0,j=1;j<=nbeta[i];j++) {
        cnt++;
        pos[i][cnt]=j;
        if (lll[i][j]==0)  {
         for(kk=1;kk<=kkbeta[i];kk++)
                bfunc[i][cnt][kk]=bfunctmp[i][j][kk];
                llltmp[i][cnt]=lll[i][j];
        } // if
        if (lll[i][j]>0)  {
         for(kk=1;kk<=kkbeta[i];kk++)
                bfunc[i][cnt][kk]=0.5*(bfunctmp[i][j  ][kk]+
                                       bfunctmp[i][j+1][kk]);
                llltmp[i][cnt]=lll[i][j];
         j++;
        } // if
        } // j,i
```

!my translated fortran code is

```
     do i =1,ntype
         cnt =0
         do j =1,nbeta(i)
             cnt = cnt+1
             pos(i,cnt) =j
             
             if(lll(i,j) ==0) then
                 do kk =1, kkbeta(i)
                     bfunc(i,cnt,kk)= bfunctmp(i,j,kk)
                 end do !end kk
                 llltmp(i,cnt) =lll(i,j)
!                 write(*,*)i,j,lll(i,j)
!                 write(*,*)i,cnt,llltmp(i,cnt)  ! '(5x,3I5)'
             end if

    !         cnt1 =j 
             if(lll(i,j) > 0) then 
                 do kk =1, kkbeta(i)
                     bfunc(i,cnt,kk)= 0.5 *(bfunctmp(i,j,kk) + bfunctmp(i,j+1,kk))
                 end do !end kk
                 llltmp(i,cnt) =lll(i,j)
               j =j+1
             end if
             
         end do !end j
     end do !end i
```

!  A do-variable within a DO body shall not appear in a variable definition context. [j]
I am looking forward to solve this issue soon. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't like the fact that `j` is assigned, since it's used in a containing DO loop.  You'll need to keep a separate counter for it that isn't used in a DO loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes  i tried to change the counter of different name but does not provide the same result. but here j is connected to pos[i][cnt]=j;

Answer (score 4):

As @TomKarzes remarked in comments, you may not assign to the control variable of a `DO` loop within the body of that loop.  Sometimes you can resolve such issues by using a different variable, instead.  In your code, however, the objective of the `j=j+1` appears to be to skip a loop iteration, and you simply cannot do that in a `DO` loop.

You can, however, replace your `DO` loop with a `DO WHILE` loop:

```
      j = 1
      do while (j <= nbeta(i))
!       ...

        if (lll(i,j) > 0) then
!           ...
            j = j + 1
        end if

        j = j + 1
      end do
```

That should work for your particular code, but you must take considerable care when making such a transformation.  There are at least these considerations that must be accounted for:

- In an iterated `DO` loop, the loop variable is automatically incremented after each execution of the loop body, even if execution of the body terminates early by execution of a `CYCLE` statement.  In a `DO WHILE` loop, however, variables are modified only by statements that are executed, so a `CYCLE` will not, itself, cause any variable to be updated.
- The number of iterations for an iterated `DO` loop to perform is computed before the first iteration is performed, based on data (such as the value of `nbeta(i)`) gathered when execution reaches the `DO` statement.  That number of iterations can be changed only by prematurely discontinuing the loop via an `EXIT`, `RETURN`, `GOTO`, or `STOP` statement, or by executing a procedure that causes the program to terminate.  On the other hand, the condition of a `DO WHILE` is evaluated before every iteration.

Comment: Thank you John.  It saves more time to me.